# Git: Put last 3 commits into branch, reset master

Tags: git

I'm trying to perform some git surgery here.  My series of commits currently looks like this:

`A->B->C->D->E->F`

and I want to transform it so that it looks like this (last commit in master is `C`):

`A->B->C`

and

`D->E->F` live in a branch off of commit `C`

How might I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply create a new branch from your current master:

```
git checkout master
git checkout -b newBranch
git push -u origin newBranch

A-B-C-D-E-F (master, NewBranch)
```

Then reset master (making sure you don't have any work in progress)

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard C

A-B-C (master)
     \
      D-E-F (newBranch)
```

You will need to `git push --force origin master`, so make sure you are the only one working on it.

Comment: Voted up, but the instructions could be much shorter: `git checkout --detach; git branch newBranch master; git branch -f master C`. checkout detach so that You are not working on master (or any other branch, for that matter).

Comment: @VonC Just to be clear: after running `git reset --hard C` (where I'm assuming `C` is the SHA), I should run `git push --force master`?  Won't my `newBranch` only be local after the first two steps?

Comment: @bclayman Yes, you have to push `newBranch` if you want it to be in the remote repo.

Comment: @tymtam Also, should the last command be `git push --force origin master`?